# Swal doesn't show up, but data is passed

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5, sweetalert

I'm trying to show a swal success message when data is passed. even though the data is passed i do not get the swal, and this shows up in the chrome console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: swal is not defined
>     success @ CustomerLoyalty:40
>     (anonymous function) @ CustomerLoyalty:217

Line 40 :

```
    <script>
    function alerts() {
        swal({   title: "Are you sure you want to delete?",   text: "You will not be able to recover this record!",   type: "warning",   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   confirmButtonText: "Delete",   closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){   swal("Deleted!", "Employee Record has been deleted", "success"); });
    }

    function success() {
        swal("Warning!","Failed to record leave!", "success")
    }
</script>
```

above is my swal functions and the "swal("Warning!","Failed to record leave!", "success")" is underlined in red when i click on the error in the console . (see screenshot)

Line 217:

```
 <form role="form" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/CustomerLoyalty">
                                                   <script type="text/javascript">success();</script>
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong here ? i have pasted the swal links as well in my header.[screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWY6h.png)

Answer (score 0):

If `swal` itself showing as `undefined` then the swal script dint load at all. Check your network tab while loading and see whether the swal js is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVEDIT

```
<script>
function alerts() {
    swal({   title: "Are you sure you want to delete?",   text: "You will not be able to recover this record!",   type: "warning",   showCancelButton: true,   confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",   confirmButtonText: "Delete",   closeOnConfirm: false }, function(){   swal("Deleted!", "Employee Record has been deleted", "success"); });
}
```

```
<script>
function success() {
    swal("Warning!","Failed to record leave!", "success");
}
```